# While Insert Records To MySQL, get in Error Code 1054

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL & I try to enter records to mysql table. I'm getting following error

> INSERT INTO advertising.discountauthorizationrequst SET DARDateTime=cast('2003-01-13 16:50:32' as datetime), `DARPubCode`=trim('DD'), `DARPubDate`=cast('2022-05-08' as date), `DARAutUser`=trim("U0001"), `DARDeviceID`=trim('123456789ABCDEFGHIJKL987456'),  `DARMessage`=trim("This Is Test Message"), `DARGranted`=("0"), `DARUser`=trim("DATAENTRYUSERNAME")    Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'DARDateTime' in 'field list'

I listed my INSERT statement below. Someone please help me to solve this issue. I'm using mysql workbench 8.0.

Columns:

```
    DARDateTime datetime PK 
    DARPubCode varchar(3) PK 
    DARPubDate date PK 
    DARAutUser varchar(5) 
    DARDeviceID varchar(50) 
    DARMessage varchar(100) 
    DARGranted varchar(1) 
    DARUser varchar(50) PK
```

Here is script

```sql
    INSERT INTO `advertising`.`discountauthorizationrequst` 
    SET 
       `DARDateTime`=cast('2003-01-13 16:50:32' as datetime), 
       `DARPubCode`=trim('DD'), 
       `DARPubDate`=cast('2022-05-08' as date), 
       `DARAutUser`=trim("U0001"),
       `DARDeviceID`=trim('123456789ABCDEFGHIJKL987456'), 
       `DARMessage`=trim("This Is Test Message"), 
       `DARGranted`=("0"), 
       `DARUser`=trim("DATAENTRYUSERNAME");
```

Edited..
Table Inspactor - DDL

```sql
    CREATE TABLE `discountauthorizationrequst` (
  `DARDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DARPubCode` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `DARPubDate` date NOT NULL,
  `DARAutUser` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DARDeviceID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DARMessage` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DARGranted` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DARUser` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DARDateTime`,`DARPubCode`,`DARPubDate`,`DARUser`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: What action would you want to do update or insert?

Comment: If you want to do insert, please use `INSERT INTO ... VALUES `  https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_insert.asp

Comment: @D-Shih MySQL supports this alternate syntax.

Comment: `INSERT INTO .... SET ` is more usefull with `UPDATE`s

Comment: The problem is before this code, since the error message says that it's near `INSERT`. I suspect you're trying to execute two queries in one call to the execute API.

Comment: Can you add this info to your question?  Right click in the table (`discountauthorizationrequst`), choose `Table inspector`, go to the Tab `DDL`, copy the info found there, and paste it (as text) in your question).

Comment: @Luuk Why does that matter for a syntax error?

Comment: @D-Shih I used INSERT INTO .... VALUES also. same error trigger.

Comment: @Barmar: It only matters to verify the cause of the error (  Which can be a simple typo...)

Comment: Why cast on insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually confusing the SQL commands and coming up with a hybrid of them.  The INSERT command most commonly is done in two ways..

```
insert into SomeTable 
   ( these, columns ) 
   values 
   ( oneValue, anotherValue)
```

or

```
insert into SomeTable( these, columns )
   select oneColumn, secondColumn
      from SomeOtherTable
      where SomeCondition
```

The UPDATE command is based on an EXISTING record that you want to change

```
Update SomeTable set
      thisColumn = SomeValue,
      anotherColumn = SomeOtherValue
   where SomeCondition
```

So, what you appear to be doing would be written as

```
INSERT INTO advertising.discountauthorizationrequst
   (  DARDateTime,
      DARPubCode,
      DARPubDate,
      DARAutUser,
      DARDeviceID,
      DARMessage,
      DARGranted, 
      DARUser
   )
   values
   (
      cast('2003-01-13 16:50:32' as datetime), 
      'DD', 
      '2022-05-08', 
      'U0001', 
      '123456789ABCDEFGHIJKL987456', 
      'This Is Test Message', 
      '0', 
      'DATAENTRYUSERNAME'
   )
```

Notice the readability with formatting, you can see each column that is needed followed by the explicit values (which could be parameterized during code later) are in the same ordinal context.  So, if you ever needed to add a new column to the insert, easy to do with the same ordinal position in the values provided secondarily to it.

As for the 3rd column, by providing a string in YYYY-MM-DD, SQL typically auto-converts to a date format.  Other fields, you dont need to explicitly TRIM() everything.  If parameterized, you would pass the trimmed VALUE, when you get to that point in your development.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake that I made. I created triggers for the above table. After I deleted those triggers its working.